# C# Regex - perform wildcard search and need to escape certain characters with linq

Tags: c#, regex, linq

i'm using EF and i've implemented a search function which support wildcard search.
For example if given search input is `%CU%P%` i will format it to become `^.*?CU.*P.*?$` and select it with `regex.isMatch`. Something like `SQL LIKE '%CU%P%'`. Example :

```
string regexSearch = GeneralHelper.RegexWildCardSearchPattern(requestDto.Name); ( it will format the % become ^.*?CU.*P.*?$)
Regex regex = new Regex(regexSearch, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
allCompetitionList = allCompetitionList.Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x.CompetitionName)).ToList();
```

But when user give me something like `%????%`, i will hit Nested Quantifier issue.
If user give me something like `%???%`, i will return nothing but in my DB i do have a record like `????`.
I've try if i manually put a input to become `%\\\?\\\?\\\?%` it will return me `????` record.

I guess i need to escape the characters by adding \\ to any characters i wish to escape except %. How can i achieve that ?

Comment: Your question is *very* unclear. What do you mean by "special character"? It would be much easier to help you if you'd provide a short but complete example demonstrating the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Rather than "how to add back slash", explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Where are you seeing the backslash? is it in the debug viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Characters with special meanings in regular expressions can be escaped by preceding them with a backslash. The .Net regular expression classes includes the [`Regex.Escape(...)` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape) to escape characters in a string.

Possibly `Regex.Escape(...)` should be used on the input string before the `GeneralHelper...` method is called. If the `GeneralHelper...` method only does what is shown in the question (ie add `^` and `$` plus replace `%` with `.` or `.*`) then the code below may be sufficient.

```
string regexSearch = GeneralHelper.RegexWildCardSearchPattern(
    Regex.Escape(requestDto.Name));
```

Comment: hi, i have updated the example of using regex..
can you guide me on how to use th regex.escape in my example above?